# Custom clean() method throws "NoneType is not iterable" error

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

As far as I know the `clean()` method cleans a form according to validation rules defined in `forms.py`.

For registering users I have created a form like this:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class RegistationForm(forms.Form):
    # More fields ...

    username = forms.CharField(
        max_length=30, min_length=3, widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={'placeholder': 'Username', 
                   'title': 'You will use this for log in.'}))

    # More fields ...
```

And for making sure that a new user does not use "@" char in username (and registers only one account with one email) I used this in my `RegisterForm`'s `clean` method:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(RegistationForm, self).clean()
    user_email = cleaned_data.get("email")
    user_username = cleaned_data.get("username")
    if "@" in user_username:                              # Line causing error
        msg = u"Usernames may contain alphanumeric, _, +, . and - characters."
        self._errors["username"] = self.error_class([msg]
        del cleaned_data["username"]

    # More validation logic ...
    return cleaned_data
```

But the problem is when I submit an empty form it gives me an `argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable` error in error line shown in `clean` method.

Shouldn't Django first check if the form is OK and only then check the error line?
Or how do I fix it? What's my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As itsjeyd says, the error is because username is empty. However, a better solution is to [define a `clean_username` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute). This will only be called if the field is not empty, and is the preferred way of validating single fields - `clean` is best for validating fields that depend on each other. In `clean_username` you raise `forms.ValidationError` rather than inserting values on the errors dict.

Answer (score 0):

If you leave the username field empty, `cleaned_data.get('username')` will return `None`. When checking whether `"@"` is `in user_username`, you are telling Python to iterate over the characters in `user_username` - which is `None`, so it can't be iterated over.

You could change your check to `if user_username and "@" in user_username` to guard against the `NoneType is not iterable` error.